# Adjectives After an Object That Comes After Transitive Verb

Tags: adjectives, sentence, sentence-patterns

I'm very aware of how verbs, indirect objects, and direct objects relate.

*I gave Sam a ball.*

Sam - indirect object and ball - direct object. Very simple! But what about when an adjective comes after a direct object?

*I find her utterly **repulsive**!*

What role does *repulsive* play in this sentence? Could this be one of those uncommon instances in which the adjective comes after the (pro)noun?

Comment: **How the heck is this a duplicate?** Come on, you-all. Not even close.

Comment: If you want to get this re-opened, you must be very clear how your question is different from the marked duplicate question, including as appropriate, what part of your question is not addressed or answered in the duplicate.

Comment: I'd like to know in detail how it **is** a duplicate. @KitZ.Fox

Comment: Then you will need to ask the users who closed it. Probably the best method is to make your case on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *predicative complement*, a complement to the verb which predicates a quality (repulsiveness) or identity of another constituent. Transitive verbs like *find*, *think*, *call* usually predicate their PCs of the object; intransitive verbs like *be*, *look*, *grow* usually predicate their PCs of the subject.

> I find <sub>DO</sub>her <sub>PC</sub>repulsive.  I think <sub>DO</sub>her <sub>PC</sub>a hideous woman.
>   She looks <sub>PC</sub>repulsive. She is <sub>PC</sub>a hideous woman.

Comment: Are you 100 percent sure nouns take predicate adjectives? I'm pretty sure only verb can take predicate adjectives and nouns.

Comment: @SebastianPojman The PC is a dependent of the verb,not a modifier of the nominal or even a part of the NP; but it describes or identifies the subject or object. In classical theory, indeed, the verb itself (beyond its minimal copular function) is a predication on the subject.

Comment: I don't understand...?

Comment: Note that in the first two examples one can also insert _to be_: _I find her to be repulsive; I think her to be a hideous woman_. They have properties that are similar to an infinitive clause, but the markers _to_ (marking an infinitive) and _be_ (marking a predicate complement) are absent, but understood.

Comment: @SebastianPojman *She is hideous*...*She* is the subject, *BE* is the verb. *Hideous* is the PC. It doesn't "modify" *she*; rather, the clause **ascribes** it to *she*--in classical theory, *BE hideous* is a **predication** on the subject *she*. The verb is sometimes called the 'predicator', and in the case of *BE* and other auxiliaries this is not unjust, since these are semantically nothing more than what classical theory called "copulas": they have no other semantic function than to sustain the predication. (They do have other syntactic and ancillary time-locative functions.)

Comment: ... With lexical verbs the copular (predicator) function is as it were folded into ...the verb; but the additional semantic content of the verb is part of the predicate, along with the predicative complement.

Comment: That still sounds crazy! I'll ask a grammarian for reassurance.